# How I can make decals glow in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making decals for the game like some symbols on the wall and I need to make these symbols glow but I have no idea how
here's an example

[image]

I tried to enable emissive with the bloom and that's what happen

[image]

I'm using HDRP

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: In your decal material just tick `Emissive` checkbox, and use a post processing volume with `bloom` module

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil I tried what u told me, see the result

Comment: Could you post material's setting?

Comment: You need separate mesh for symbols and then make them glow not too complicated!

Comment: if you can't do this edit these symbols in any editing software and add glow on them

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same!
It seems you'll need to mask the area using a black and white texture. Black is notEmissive and white is fullEmissive.
Hope it works for you.

Just put this "black and White" texture in the "Emission map".